# json post body help, using retrofit and jsonObject

Tags: java, json, retrofit2

As simple as this json looks I cannot get it formatted correctly to post in body.

```
{
    "requests": [
        {
            "action": "reject",
            "justification": "admin reason",
            "requestId": "ee4a5b4f3af54d849a63e305c13f6c8d"
        }
    ],
    "justification": "admin reason"
}
```

Here is what I have so far in Android studio using retrofit2

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
    .setLenient()
    .create();
Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl("https://myurl.com/")
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson));
JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
JsonObject jsonObjectN = new JsonObject();
jsonObject.addProperty("action", action);
jsonObject.addProperty("request_id", request_id);
jsonObject.addProperty("justification", "blablabla");
jsonObjectN.add("requests", jsonObject);
jsonObjectN.addProperty("justification", justification);
Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();
Client client = retrofit.create(Client.class);
Call<PostRequest> user = client.postRequests(jsonObjectN);
```

In client class I have

```
@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
@POST("/requests")
Call<PostRequest> postRequests(@Body JsonObject body

);
```

So the request is like this

```
Request{method=POST, url=https://myurl.com/v1.0/approver/requests, tags={class retrofit2.Invocation=com.loginci.rgcislogin.Client.postRequests() [{"requests":{"action":"reject","request_id":"23423423refsdsdgdg","justification":"blablabla"},"justification":"Action done by Admin"}]}}
```

Very close but I cant quite figure out how to make it in the exact array/json format as its expecting?? 
Hopefully someone knows Android and jsonObject well enough to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not adding a json array request

Try the following.

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
    .setLenient()
    .create();
Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl("https://myurl.com/")
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson));
JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
JsonObject jsonObjectN = new JsonObject();
JsonArray jsonArray = new JsonArray();
jsonObject.addProperty("action", action);
jsonObject.addProperty("request_id", request_id);
jsonObject.addProperty("justification", "blablabla");
jsonArray.add(jsonObject);
jsonObjectN.add("requests", jsonArray);
jsonObjectN.addProperty("justification", justification);
Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();
Client client = retrofit.create(Client.class);
Call<PostRequest> user = client.postRequests(jsonObjectN);
```

Comment: Thank you!! I couldnt find examples of how to do this. So now I put a break after and getting
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $
Im assuming that is on the response back? 
I did take a valid post response from postman and put it in pojo to render then made a class and calling that on response but must not be right, im thinking. I know if json is not correct api responds with just [] if it is then it responds with real json response